# Unity 4.6.x Editor Application crashes on load OS X Yosemite

Tags: macos, unity-game-engine, crash, osx-yosemite

Asking this on SO as well as the Unity network, hoping someone can give me a hand.. I'm running into an issue that seems to be specific to 4.6.x versions of Unity. First, the specs: I'm running a Mac Mini with an i7 Processor, 8GB of ram and OS X Yosemite.

Now, I've been able to run Unity 5.x without any issues (This is my last resort, If I have to I'll end up running Unity 5.x, but I'd rather run 4.6.x), but when I attempt to run any Unity 4.6.x version, the **editor application itself** attempts to start up, and immediately crashes. I've attempted uninstalling & removing preferences, rebooting, different versions, etc to no avail. Has anyone run into this issue before, if so what was the fix? I've heard that this was a known issue at one point, but was fixed in Unity 4.6.1 (which I've attempted to run unsuccessfully...)

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know if this applies to Unity 4.6, but try adding [this code](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/mac-os-builds-crashing-in-unity-5.316489/#post-2066410) somewhere: `void OnGUI() { 
GUI.contentColor = new Color(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f); 
GUILayout.Label ("Test"); 
}`

Comment: Yeah it's not even getting that far.. It's literally crashing 5 seconds after I attempt to open the editor application

Comment: I'll update the question to clarify. Thanks for the response though!